# Trusted Contributors - what is your feeling on answers like this?

Tags: discussion

https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/12722/1671

Essentially it's a cut and paste of an article posted on an presumable for-profit AI education site/venture: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/01/learning-path-data-scientist-machine-learning-2019/

I had deleted a former version of this answer for lack of attribution.

Technically, it's a form of promotion, but that doesn't necessarily invalidate the info.

- **Post your opinions.  I'm looking for guidance and some consensus on how the trusted, active members of the community want me to deal with this kind of post.**

(Context: I tend to always give OP's the benefit of the doubt, and err on the side of permissibility.  Sometimes that's a strength, sometimes a weakness.  But it's you folks who are driving this community, so you preferences on the matter must outweigh my own inclinations.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, in an academic setting, this would be considered plagiarism, even though you cite or attribute it. If we accept this type of answers, we might encourage users do it again (which would not bring anything new to the web) or to adopt this strategy to easily increase their reputation.

So, I am against this type of answers (especially, if the author of the answer is not the author of the cited article).

Comment: Very good points.  Duplicate information, of dubious value for us. In addition, low effort.  We risk diminishing our reliability by allowing what constitutes advertising and promotion.